# Adding office 365 mail in wordpress code not working

Tags: wordpress, office365, phpmailer

I have tried to setup office 365 for sending mails from website and added the code to functions.php in my current theme also when i setup smtp details of gmail it works. When i configure office 365 it was not working i have even tried ports but none of them is working.

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'wpse8170_phpmailer_init' );
function wpse8170_phpmailer_init( PHPMailer $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->Host = 'your.smtp.server.here';
    $phpmailer->Port = 25; // could be different
    $phpmailer->Username = 'your_username@example.com'; // if required
    $phpmailer->Password = 'yourpassword'; // if required
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true; // if required
    // $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // enable if required, 'tls' is another possible value

    $phpmailer->IsSMTP();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't define what you mean by "not working", but I'll take a guess. Most services will not allow authentication over insecure connections. Strictly speaking you should be submitting to an SMTP submission service, like this:

```
$phpmailer->Host = 'your.smtp.server.here';
$phpmailer->Port = 587;
$phpmailer->Username = 'your_username@example.com';
$phpmailer->Password = 'yourpassword';
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Comment: I have changed this settings too even after that too. Mails are not going through office365 email. WHich i have added in the smtp details like the above.

Comment: Define "not going through". What do you logs say? What happens when you enable debug output?

Comment: You will need to look up the docs for the server you’re using. I can’t tell from what you’ve posted.